# Golang загрузка больших файлов Google Drive

Tags: golang, fileupload, google-drive

Есть задача загружать большие файлы (txt,docx,csv,xls) на Google Drive через API средствами с немедленной конвертацией в форматы Google языка Go, при реализации нашей программы выгрузки мы столкнулись проблемой загрузки файлов более 5МБ, так как для загрузки файлов методом:

> Simple upload: uploadType=media

всё да вольно тривиально. Но мы не смогли пока придумать как с помощью библиотеки https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client сделать загрузку методом:

> Resumable upload: uploadType=resumable

Так как нам необходимо выгружать таблиц по 500MB(и в плоть до 10GB) и более.

**Суть: нужен рабочий пример на Golang реализации функции загрузки больших (>500MB, но также поддерживающий и любой меньший размер) файлов на Google Drive через API.**

Кусок существующего кода отвечающий за загрузку файла:

```
showProgress := func(current, total int64) {
    fmt.Printf("Uploaded at %s, %s/%s\r", getRate(current), Comma(current), Comma(total))
}

r, err := d.Files.Insert(f).ResumableMedia(context.Background(), input, inputInfo.Size(), mimeType).Convert(true).ProgressUpdater(showProgress).Do()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("An error occurred: %v\n", err)
    return nil, err
}
```

Результат:

```
An error occurred: googleapi: Error 400: Bad Request, badRequest
```

Answer (score 2):

Наши желания по загрузке данных в Google таблицы не могут быть реализованы в коде по причине того что на данный счёт есть целый ряд ограничений, и наш объём данных не может быть с конвертирован в форматы Google. Мы сможем использовать Google Drive только для хранения оригинальных файлов.

> Какие файлы можно хранить на Google Диске
>
> Размеры файлов Ниже перечислены ограничения на размеры документов,
>   таблиц и презентаций, которые можно хранить на Google Диске.
>
> Документы. Максимум 1 020 000 символов. Размер текстовых документов,
>   преобразуемых в формат Google, не может превышать 50 МБ.
>
> Таблицы. Максимум 2 миллиона ячеек для файлов, созданных в Google
>   Таблицах или преобразуемых в этот формат. Презентации. Максимальный
>   размер файлов, преобразуемых в формат Google, составляет 100 МБ.
>
> Другие файлы. Максимум 5 ТБ. Поддерживаемые типы файлов Ниже
>   перечислены форматы файлов, которые можно открыть на Google Диске.
>
> Обычные файлы:
>
> архивы (ZIP, RAR, TAR, GZIP); аудиофайлы (MP3, MPEG, WAV, OGG);
>   изображения (JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP); файлы разметки/кода (CSS, HTML,PHP,
>   C, CPP, H, HPP, JS); текстовые файлы (TXT); видео (WebM, MPEG4, 3GPP,
>   MOV, AVI, MPEGPS, WMV, FLV, OGG); Файлы Adobe:
>
> Autodesk AutoCad (DXF); Illustrator (AI); Photoshop (PSD); документы
>   переносимого формата (PDF); Postscript (EPS, PS); масштабируемые
>   векторные рисунки (SVG); изображения TIFF (рекомендуется при
>   использовании режима RGB); TrueType (TTF). Файлы Microsoft:
>
> Excel (XLS и XLSX); PowerPoint (PPT и PPTX); Word (DOC и DOCX); XML
>   Paper Specification (XPS).
>
> [Оригинал -> Cправка - Диск](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=ru)